# Column xdf transpose

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, transpose

I am at my wits end and have tried all ways to find the cause of error.
My data has three columns. column A has names and Column B has date ( in descending order ) and Column C has numerical values. The rows are 61K +.
I am trying to transpose this data in such a manner in this manner.

Names Date       Date           Date         and so on
AAA   15MAY_61   14MAY_55       13MAY_50
BBB              14MAY_101
CCC                             13MAY_200    11MAY_190

[image: <code>file image</code>]

```
Sub TST_2105()
Dim rw As Long, rc As Long, rr As Long, r As Long, C As Long

With Sheets("Sheet4")    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
    rr = Application.Match("Ticker", .Columns(1), 0)
    rc = .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
    .Cells(rr, rc + 1) = .Cells(rr + 1, 2).Value2

    For rw = rr + 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)) Then
            .Cells(Rows.Count, rc).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
        End If
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Cells(rr, rc).Resize(1, 999), 0)) Then
            .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
        End If

        r = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)
        C = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Rows(rr), 0)
        .Cells(r, C) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value & "_" & .Cells(rw, 3).Value
    Next rw

    With .Cells(rr, rc).CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
             .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
             .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

The code works but it adds many blank columns in between so much so that the columns encounter xdf error. I know that the unique dates are about 1570 ( columns) and unique names are about 1640( rows).
I will be much obliged if anyone can rectify the error. 
PKJ

Comment: You have 1570 unique dates but this line `Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Cells(rr, rc).Resize(1, 999), 0)` only searches 999.so you will get duplicate date columns created.

Comment: I am not sure what 'Transpose` means in your way of asking... It usually means (in Excel) moving columns on rows, but in your case it looks to means something else. Can you insert pictures with existing situation and what you try accomplishing? Your "Names Date Date Date" does not say to much. Would you really transposing, but because of limited number of columns, when maximum is reached, to continue from the next available row? Or, only the duplicates problem must be understood and solved?

Comment: Did you not see the image? It shows the input data and the desired output.

Comment: I could see it, but I did not exactly understand what it means... Now, saying that, I could. For you, who dealt with it from some time, it looks simple. Now, it is late in my country, but tomorrow I will prepare an answer. The most appropriate way to deal with big ranges is to use arrays and everything to be done in memory. And processing result to be dropped at once on the worksheet. I think I have a scenario (for now, only in my head) to transform it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` and available in Excel 2010+.

I assume you do not have duplicate tickers on the same date, as none are shown.
Given that, after formatting the dates and values, the operation is a simple Pivot with no aggregation.

- Add a custom column to format the date as text

  `=Date.ToText([Date],"dd-MM-yyyy")`
- Add another custom column to combine the text formatted date and Value

  `=[Custom] & "_" & Text.From([Value])`
- Pivot on the textual date column selecting no aggregation

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Ticker", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Value", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Date.ToText([Date],"dd-MM-yyyy")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each [Custom] & "_" & Text.From([Value])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Date", "Value"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Custom]), "Custom", "Custom.1")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Will give a try on Monday. I haven’t used much of  power query and was looking for a vba solution.

Comment: @pradeep You can do it with VBA, but I think the coding is simpler with PQ.

Comment: Though I know nothing about PQ and since you provided the M code I managed to insert that in the editor some how. My first PQ effort.

Comment: @pradeep If you examine the steps on the right side of the screen in the UI, you can see what was done.  And if you double click on the steps `Added Custom` and `Added Custom1`, you can see the formulas that were used to create the results.  If you really want a VBA solution, I can post one, but PQ is simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I built some range to be tested, in order to create a code able to do what (I understood) you need. But firstly, having a testing environment, I tested your code. My conclusion is the next: It works well, with small adjustment, but there may be some problems with your data to be processed:

1. It is really possible that all available columns to be filled, in such a case the code does not return an error, it just wrongly calculate the cells where to return the processing result. I placed a small improvement and, based of that, the code warns about the columns maximum limit, informs about the maximum row which has been processed and stops the code. The code can be adapted to return the rest of unprocessed rows on a new created sheet. But not this was the object of the question;
2. It is possible that not all the cells in column "B:B" to be correctly formatted as Date and the matching cannot be done between a Date value and a string one. The code can be improved with a preliminary check, from this point of view. I would suggest you to check that, simple putting a formula in the first empty cell, to return `Day` from B:B cells and see if all of them return correctly;
3. The way of resizing the range to match Date ('Resize(1, 999)`) has been improved, to search up to the last filled cell. In its original way, it could miss some existing Date values in the first row;
4. Minor changes have been done, in order to improve speed performance. The code deletes the previous range obtained in the precedent test, uses some lines to increase the speed (`ScreenUpdating = False, EnableEvents = False, Calculation = xlCalculationManual`) and other minor ones I do not remember now.

Please test the code and send some feedback.

```
Sub TST_2105()
 Dim rw As Long, rc As Long, rr As Long, r As Long, C As Long
 Dim lastRow As Long, lngUniqD As Long, boolColMax As Boolean

 With Sheets("Sheet4")    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
    rr = Application.Match("Ticker", .Columns(1), 0)
    'clear the range where tests has been done:
    .Range(.Cells(1, rr + 4), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, rr + 4).End(xlUp).Row, Columns.Count)).ClearContents
    rc = .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
    .Cells(rr, rc) = .Cells(rr, 1).Value2

    'these lines increase the code speed with about 60%
    'They can be commented in order to see what happens on the sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For rw = rr + 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)) Then
            .Cells(Rows.Count, rc).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
        End If
        'Here the code take care of the maximum available Excell columns:
        If .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 16383 Then boolColMax = True
        'Here I adapted the code to search up to the (really) last column with Date:
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, _
                .Cells(rr, rc).Resize(1, .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 4))) Then
            .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
        End If

        r = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)
        C = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Rows(rr), 0)
        .Cells(r, C) = .Cells(rw, 2).value & "_" & .Cells(rw, 3).value
        If boolColMax Then MsgBox "The code reaches the maximum Excel available columns." & vbCrLf & _
                        "(being processed " & rw & " rows. Now, processing will stop...", vbInformation, _
                        "Maximum available Columns riched": GoTo OverColLimit
    Next rw
OverColLimit: 'label to jump at in case of maximum columns limit has been reched
    With .Cells(rr, rc).CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
             .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
             .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End With
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: The msg box for "max column reached" appeared and processing stopped; data was not processed after date 30-10-2017. Ironically, after @CDP1802 pointed that resize (1,999) was duplicating the columns, I changed it to resize(1,1999) for testing and it worked without error. The last column was indeed for 01-01-2014 as desired.

Comment: But i replaced that part  by `Resize(1, .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 4)))`, meaning to check up to the last column...

Comment: When I am free I will add a function to your code to find unique number of dates from column B ( that will the last column) should be 1570 approx and put that in your resize parameter so that in future if further dates are added it will be taken care of.

Comment: @pradeep I thought that my above presented way of resizing makes this effort useless. But if you want that it is easy to use AdvancedFilter for unique values in another columns and only count them. I did that in my initial attempt, but I abandoned the way after trying of your code. Anyway, I am glad you made the code working...

Answer (score 0):

With help from everyone I have this solution. I wanted it in VBA.

```
Sub TST_2105new()
    Dim rw As Long, rc As Long, rr As Long, r As Long, C As Long, lr2 As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2") '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
    lr2 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'rows of input data
    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    With sh
        lastcol = Unique(rng) ' to know number of columns appearing in report
        TickerCount = Unique(rng2) ' to know the number of Tickers
        rr = Application.Match("Ticker", .Columns(1), 0)
        rc = .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
        .Cells(rr, rc + 1) = .Cells(rr + 1, 2).Value2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For rw = rr + 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)) Then
                .Cells(Rows.Count, rc).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
            End If
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Cells(rr, rc).Resize(1, lastcol), 0)) Then
                .Cells(rr, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
            End If

            r = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)
            C = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Rows(rr), 0)
            .Cells(r, C) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value & "_" & .Cells(rw, 3).Value
        Next rw

        With .Cells(rr, rc).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                 .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
                 .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
            End With
        End With

    End With
End Sub

Function Unique(ListRange As Range) As Integer

Dim CellValue As Variant

Dim UniqueValues As New Collection

Application.Volatile

On Error Resume Next

For Each CellValue In ListRange

UniqueValues.Add CellValue, CStr(CellValue) ' add the unique item

Next

Unique = UniqueValues.Count

End Function
```